# Find records with a value outside a specific range in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find records in MongoDB that are created outside a specific period. The query to search for records inside a specific period is pretty straightforward:

```
db.test.find({"Published":{'$gt':"2011-08-02", '$lt':"2011-08-06"}})
```

So naturally, I tried this for "outside" a specific range:

```
db.test.find({'$not':{"Published":{'$gt':"2011-08-02", '$lt':"2011-08-06"}}})
```

But this returns an empty result, while there are definately records published then.
What query should I use instead? Can anyone help me? I'm using raw mongo queries.

Thanks in advance

--- UPDATE ---

I found that the following query works, but it doesn't look like the perfect solution:

```
db.test.find(
  {'$or': [
    {"Published":{'$lt':"2011-02-02"}},
    {"Published":{'$gt':"2011-08-06"}}
  ]}
)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Your dates seem to be strings, as denoted by the hyphens. You might want to use `ISODate()`.

Comment: I know it's not ideal, but I'm working on someone else's project. It gets the values from an external source, where they're strings. The comparison works though, that's not the issue.

Comment: And how should MongoDB know the semantics of a String? It will be a lexicographics comparison. But that's not the core problem. See my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting the `$not` in the wrong place. Try this:

```js
db.test.find({"Published":{ $not:{$gt:"2011-08-02", $lt:"2011-08-06"} } })
```

For details, see the [MongoDB docs about the `$not`operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#not).

Edit as because of the comment this solution would not work:

```js
> db.dates.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5492d46ef6226b581c80c0a2"), "a" : 1, "date" : "2011-08-04" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5492d4e2f6226b581c80c0a3"), "a" : 2, "date" : "2011-08-07" }

> db.dates.find({date:{$not:{$gt:"2011-08-02",$lt:"2011-08-06"}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5492d4e2f6226b581c80c0a3"), "a" : 2, "date" : "2011-08-07" }
```

Comment: I already tried that prior to posting this comment, this doesn't work.

Comment: It does. Doublechecked on my machine.

Comment: I just tried it again as well, literally copying your string, and it didn't work for me... Not sure why, maybe because it's strings instead of dates

Comment: See edit. This has nothing to do with Strings or dates.